# Read *.wav file in golang

Tags: php, go, wav

I've used `file_get_contents` for reading a WAV file in PHP and I want to use package [`github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/wav`](https://github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/tree/master/wav) for same task in Go. But there is not any simple example about this package. I am new to Go and do not understand it. Is there anyone guiding me or suggest another way?

Code in PHP:

```php
$wsdl = 'http://myApi.asmx?WSDL';
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl));
$data = file_get_contents(public_path() . "/forTest/record.wav");
$param = array(
  'userName' => '***',
  'password' => '***',
  'file' => $data);

$res = $client->UploadMessage($param);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you do not need to use this package `github.com/mjibson/go-dsp/wav`. `file_get_contents` function is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string.

In Go, you can do something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func public_path() string {
    return "/public/path/"
}

func main() {
    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile(public_path() + "/forTest/record.wav")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Print(string(dat))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/l9R0940iK50

Comment: the repo the OP mentions parses the wav file header ... your code does not handle particulars of reading audio

Comment: You approach is too general. with this code you can uselessly read any file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to read the file, it really does not matter whether it is .wav or some other file. You can use `go's` builtin package `io/ioutil`.

Following is what you should do in `go` to read a disk file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    // Reading .wav file from disk.

    fileData, err := ioutil.ReadFile("DISK_RELATIVE_PATH_PREFIX" + "/forTest/record.wav")

    // ioutil.ReadFile returns two results, 
    // first one is data (slice of byte i.e. []byte) and the other one is error.
    // If error is having nil value, you got successfully read the file, 
    // otherwise you need to handle the error.

    if err != nil {
        // Handle error here.

        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        // Do whatever needed with the 'fileData' such as just print the data, 
        // or send it over the network.

        fmt.Print(fileData)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given a WAV file this returns its payload as a floating point audio curve along with essential audio file details like bit-depth, sample-rate and num-channels.

Had you simply read in the binary audio file using one of the underlying IO primitives in order to obtain the audio curve you would have to battle with your own bit shifting to pluck multi-byte `int`s as well as handling big or little endianness.

You still must be aware of how to handle multi-channel interleaving of audio samples from each channel which is not an issue for mono audio.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/youpy/go-wav"
    "math"
)

func read_wav_file(input_file string, number_of_samples uint32) ([]float64, uint16, uint32, uint16) {

    if number_of_samples == 0 {
        number_of_samples = math.MaxInt32
    }

    blockAlign := 2
    file, err := os.Open(input_file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    reader := wav.NewReader(file)
    wavformat, err_rd := reader.Format()
    if err_rd != nil {
        panic(err_rd)
    }

    if wavformat.AudioFormat != wav.AudioFormatPCM {
        panic("Audio format is invalid ")
    }

    if int(wavformat.BlockAlign) != blockAlign {
        fmt.Println("Block align is invalid ", wavformat.BlockAlign)
    }

    samples, err := reader.ReadSamples(number_of_samples) // must supply num samples w/o defaults to 2048
    //                                                    // just supply a HUGE number then actual num is returned
    wav_samples := make([]float64, 0)

    for _, curr_sample := range samples {
        wav_samples = append(wav_samples, reader.FloatValue(curr_sample, 0))
    }

    return wav_samples, wavformat.BitsPerSample, wavformat.SampleRate, wavformat.NumChannels
}

func main() {

    input_audio := "/blah/genome_synth_evolved.wav"

    audio_samples, bits_per_sample, input_audio_sample_rate, num_channels := read_wav_file( input_audio, 0)

    fmt.Println("num samples ", len(audio_samples)/int(num_channels))
    fmt.Println("bit depth   ",  bits_per_sample)
    fmt.Println("sample rate ", input_audio_sample_rate)
    fmt.Println("num channels", num_channels)
}
```